# Auto generate multiple rows from one query php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am new here and I have coders block, please assist, I am trying to get multiple results from one query and create new rows of values from it.e.g I want row 1 to generate row 2 and 3 where row 1 is a general transaction, row 2 is interest made from row 1 which is 1% and commission made in row 3 at 0.5%, is it possible to generate a query that will output the following results?

```
Date       |  End Date   |  Shop  |  Trans   |  Amount  |  Ref No
-----------|-------------|--------|----------|----------|---------
16/9/2016  |  16/10/2016 |   FGB  |   Payed  |   10 000 |    251        
15/10/2016 |  xxxxxxxxx  |   xxx  |   xxxx   |   100    |    251      
15/10/2016 |  xxxxxxxxx  |   xxx  |   xxxx   |   50     |    251
```

These results should be in one table is it this possible? Thanks In Advance.

Comment: queries cannot generate new rows out of nothingness. you can easily write code to INSERT those rows for you, but you can't have a `select ...`-type query take one row and magically turn it into 3.

Comment: I am not sure about MySQL capabilities but in MS SQL you can do that with triggers, where a single INSERT can trigger SQL code that does anything you want, including additional INSERT statements. If MySQL has similar trigger functionality, that's where I would start looking.

Comment: Thanks Marc B & @SunKnight0.I understand that you can't generate data from nothing, are triggers the only solution because I know how get data from the database but I would like to retrieve the data (row 1) perform calculations and output those results on the same table following each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you cannot make new row out like that. **But** you can create columns.

In that case you can run example like

```
select 
  *, 
  Amount * 0.01 as interest, 
  Amount * 0.005 as commission 
from your_mega_table;
```

And if you modify your code you can get 3 versions of row with different amounts.

Otherwise you need to do some kind of cron script or trigger or stored procedure in database, that will solve your case.

Comment: Thanks @Spell,  It seems that, that is the only way through cron script/ trigger or stored procedures. Can you give an example of how I would go about this?

Comment: For me i recommend you to insert other rows in the moment when you insert main row. In context of your problem i understand that you work with money. In this case you must fix all calculations in db, couse if you will change your code in future, you will need to leave legacy code and support it. But if you will store data in db - no legacy code will remain needed.

Comment: Thanks @Spell, I think I will go with the database codes, although it's my first time it seems to make more sense. Thank you for your time and answers. Blessings Be.